# Is it possible to use the class-Image method even the object is ImageView

Tags: java, network-programming, javafx-8

I am writing a JAVA program using JavaFx. There are two programs. The duty of  each program is server and client. The client will send the image to the server. I used `ImageView` class to handle the image. To send the image to the server, I think I will create a two-dimensional array of `int` and store each pixel of the image in the array so I will send it through a socket. ***However***, `ImageView` class doesn't have method to handle the pixel. I found that `Image` class does have it. And I don't want to change the class. So does anyone know how to deal with the problem. In addition, a picture below is what I wrote:

```
public void sendImage(ImageView sentObject)
    {
    int[][] pixel= new int[592][559];
    try
        {
        for(int j=0;j<559;j++)
            {
            for(int i=0;i<592;i++)
            pixel[i][j]=sentObject.getPixelReader().getColor(i,j);
            }
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject(sentObject);
        out.flush();
        }
    catch(IOException IO)
        {
        IO.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

However, it got an error:

```
 error: cannot find symbol
                pixel[i][j]=sentObject.getPixelReader().getColor(i,j);
                                      ^
  symbol:   method getPixelReader()
  location: variable sentObject of type ImageView
```

Below is the hierarchy [ 1 ]:

[image]

Reference

1. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/package-tree.html

Comment: Just use `sentObject.getImage().getPixelReader(...)`

Comment: Thank you  James_D. It got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

To send and receive an `Image` object, you can serialize it through a `BufferedImage` object with `javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils`:
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html

You can also write it into an Image file and then send the file to the server, depending on how many images you have to send.

> error: cannot find symbol
>                   pixel[i][j]=sentObject.getPixelReader().getColor(i,j);
>                                         ^
>     symbol:   method getPixelReader()
>     location: variable sentObject of type ImageView

In your example, I don't understand how you could obtain a `PixelReader` object from an `ImageView` referring to the JavaDoc:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html